# What is fingerprint template format?

Tags: templates, format, fingerprint

I'm planning to develop a system integrating fingerprint scanner. By reading some sdk's, I always encounter template format such as:
ANSI INCITS 378-2004 and ISO/IEC 19794-2:2005

I was having hard time understanding it. I know template is the term used to store fingerprint, but how do these format differ from each other and does template came from minutiae?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biometric fingerprint template formats you mentioned are standardized and widely accepted end let's say like 'encoding' type of the collation of a fingerprint template's minutia data that independent fingerprint reader scanners manufacturers can use to save fingerprint data for archiving. An organization can decide to use ANSI 381 for all saved fingerprint data irrespective of any type of fingerprint reader scanner used for e.g. department X and opt to save all finger data for department Y in ISO 19794-2 format. They differ from each other based on their underlying encoding and one format will not match with that of another even if from same person's fingerprint.  At least from my experience as a developer of biometric software solutions, that is what I have observed.

You can learn something about ISO 19794-2 from Source AFIS project here https://sourceafis.machinezoo.com/.

**June 2019 update** (by author of the mentioned website): Actual format of ANSI 378 (and partially ISO 19794-2) is described here: https://templates.machinezoo.com/. That should clear any doubt about what is in these files.

Comment: do you know which is more common or better to use (ANSI 378 VS iso 19794-2) ?

Comment: There are many other proprietor templates including those two and others too. All are good in their various respective ways. Just make sure to read in detail about the one your organization wants to use so that you know how best to support your application. None of them is bad otherwise it would not be in use.