# In which format fingerprint scanner stores fingerprint?

Tags: android, security, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

i am working working on project that involves fingerprint Scanner, i wanted that fingerprint to be stored in something, say a database.
I searched the web, but there was no substantial information regarding this topic. It might be stored in an image format, but if that it, then is it safe enough ?

Comment: http://biometrics.mainguet.org/types/fingerprint/fingerprint_algo.htm

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103773/what-is-fingerprint-template-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fingerprint templates are features about the finger. The typical image will not be stored in the scanner. But during the capture, it can return the fingerprint image (bmp/jpeg/png) if requires.

Every scanner has its own format of templates. ISO 19794-2 and ANSI-378 are some standard formats.

You can maintain both template and image at your database.

If you maintain

- **Image**: You can compare with standard image processing algorithms. ***But may not safe*** as getting the image by intruder may lead the security issues. But ***flexible*** as the comparison can be done at the programming level.
- **Template**: You need the scanner to compare the templates. ***May be Safe*** , (provided if the software is developed with [security features](http://camsunit.com/application/html-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#security) considered) as it would require the scanner and the live fingerprint for the comparison, but ***not flexible*** as it requires always scanner.

Now it is up to you about choosing the right fingerprint management as per your application requirement.